# Adding a space in concatenation in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on this assignment that asks me to calculate the BMI using weight, height. I'm done with the entire code. However, I have tried everything to add a space in the print statements, and I'm not sure why adding the + is not working in between the variable and the string. I haven't added the variable in the first two print statements, because I just want to see what the issue is first.

I have attached the output, and what I've worked on so far, I am still a beginner, so any detailed feedback would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.lang.Math;
import java.lang.System;

class Main { 
  public static void main(String\[\]args){
//make a scanner object 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//prompt the user to enter name
    System.out.println("Enter patients name: ");
//store user's input into string called name
    String name = scan.nextLine();
//prompt user to enter height 
    System.out.print("Enter height in meters: ");
//store user's height into string 
    String height = scan.nextLine();

//prompt the user to enter weight 
    System.out.print("Enter weight: "); 
//store user's weight into string 
    String weight = scan.nextLine(); 

//calculate the BMI using height and weight of the user 
    Double x = Double.parseDouble(weight)/Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(height),2); 
    System.out.println(x);
  //if the BMI is less than 20, print that the patient is underweight 
    if(x < 20){
      System.out.println("The patient is underweight");
      }
//if the BMI is between 20 and 25, then print that the user is average 
    else if(x > 20 && x < 25){
      System.out.println("The patient is average");
      }
//if the BMI is greater than 25, print that the patient is overweight 
    else if(x > 25){
      System.out.println (name + "is overweight"); 
      }
  }
}
```

```
'*.java')
java -classpath .:target/dependency/* Main
Enter patients name: 
Liam
Enter height in meters: 2
Enter weight: 200
50.0
Liamis overweight
```

([command line output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEm6Y.png))

Comment: `System.out.println (name + " is overweight"); `

Answer (score 0):

## Inputs lack a SPACE, so output lacks a SPACE

If the value stored in variable named `name` does not contain a SPACE, and if the string literal `"is overweight"` does not contain a SPACE, then why would you expect the concatenated result to contain a SPACE?

You could redefine either part to contain a SPACE.

```
name + " is overweight"  // SPACE added to front of string literal.
```

Or you could concatenate three parts, using a SPACE as the middle part.

```
name + " " + "is overweight". // Middle part is a string literal containing a single character, a SPACE.
```

Or you could join the parts while specifying a SPACE in between. Use the [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)) static method.

```
String.join( " " , name , "is overweight" )
```